# Error installing kivy library at windows terminal and anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Recently I was  trying to install kivy library to use in one project, I've followed this tutorial from official website of the library:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

But,nonetheless, I get a lot of errors from windows cmd terminal:

> ````
> command:
> 'C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u
> -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7kupr225\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7kupr225\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qwvz28d8'
>        cwd: C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kupr225\kivy\  
> Complete output (531 lines):   Using setuptools   User distribution
> detected, avoid portable command.   Using this graphics system: OpenGL
> WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags
> gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
>
>   b"Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search
> path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing
> `gstreamer-1.0.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
> variable\r\nNo package 'gstreamer-1.0' found\r\n"
>
>   WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags
> gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
>
>   b"Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search
> path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing
> `gstreamer-1.0.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
> variable\r\nNo package 'gstreamer-1.0' found\r\n"
>
>   WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags
> sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)
>
>   b"Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search
> path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing
> `sdl2.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package
> 'sdl2' found\r\nPackage SDL2_ttf was not found in the pkg-config
> search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing
> `SDL2_ttf.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo
> package 'SDL2_ttf' found\r\nPackage SDL2_image was not found in the
> pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory
> containing `SDL2_image.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
> variable\r\nNo package 'SDL2_image' found\r\nPackage SDL2_mixer was
> not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the
> directory containing `SDL2_mixer.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
> environment variable\r\nNo package 'SDL2_mixer' found\r\n"
>
>   ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi  
> ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency
> for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency
> for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR:
> Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency
> for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency
> for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for
> cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi   ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx
> build_ext   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed
> building wheel for kivy```
>
> **other errors:**
> -----------------
> ````

Others error:

````
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
     command: 'C:\Users\lucas\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gqowcu2q\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gqowcu2q\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_9otg0p0\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lucas\kivy_venv\include\site\python3.8\kivy'
         cwd: C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gqowcu2q\kivy\
    Complete output (513 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' n\xc6o \x82 reconhecido como um comando interno\r\nou externo, um programa oper\xa0vel ou um arquivo em lotes.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' n\xc6o \x82 reconhecido como um comando interno\r\nou externo, um programa oper\xa0vel ou um arquivo em lotes.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' n\xc6o \x82 reconhecido como um comando interno\r\nou externo, um programa oper\xa0vel ou um arquivo em lotes.\r\n"

    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'C:\Users\lucas\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gqowcu2q\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lucas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gqowcu2q\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_9otg0p0\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\lucas\kivy_venv\include\site\python3.8\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

I've tried to install in anaconda terminal too, the installing looks good , the terminal said that it was successfully, but when I try to run it in the spyder, I've got theses traceback errors:

> `enter code here Reloaded modules: ai [WARNING] [Lang        ] The
>   file C:\Users\lucas\OneDrive\Documentos\Artificial IntelligentA-Z  -
>   Learn how to bulid an AI\Code
>   templates\P20-Self-Driving-Car\Self_Driving_Car\car.kv is loaded
>   multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors. [CRITICAL] [App
>
>   Unable to get a Window, abort. An exception has occurred, use %tb to
>   see the full traceback`

I use these commands:

```
    >python -m pip uninstall -y kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.gstreamer 
    kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.angle  
    >python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv  
    >python -m virtualenv kivy_venv  
    >ivy_venv\Scripts\activate  
    >source kivy_venv/Scripts/activate 
    >python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 >kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* 
    >kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
    >python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
    >python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

**Note**
My python version is 3.8
Anaconda version is 3.7

Comment: which command from the website did you use for the installation?

Comment: Also, you tagged anaconda, but your python in `C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` does not seem to be from the anaconda distribution

Comment: @FlyingTeller I use the commands from this link:https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html.

Comment: I put anaconda tag, because I've got  errors in anaconda enviorment too.

Comment: @LucasVital _I put anaconda tag, because I’ve got errors in anaconda enviorment too._ Can you add those to your post, then?

Comment: sure, no problems

Comment: I've added the commands in the post few times a ago, now you can see the commands that I used.